# Can kafka client select specific partition to consume?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a single kafka client instance that is consuming from 200 partitions, now I want it to consume only on the first 3 kafka partition for debugging and sampling purpose.

Is there a way I can do that?

Or alternatively I can consume from all partition and drop message from partition that is not from the first 3 partition. Is there a way I can find out which partition is the message from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `KafkaConsumer.assign(java.util.Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)` to assign a specific set of partitions. To find out the parttion of the message you can use `ConsumerRecord.partition()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want consume only partially partition,
implement org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.PartitionAssignor

already apache kafka's test use MockPartitionAssignor (extends PartitionAssignor)

implement PartitionAssignor and, setup "partition.assignment.strategy"
reference : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified which consumer API you use, I am going to give an example based on the Python [kafka-python](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/kafka-python/latest/kafka-python.pdf) library.

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
group_id='my-group',
bootstrap_servers=['host:9092'])

for message in consumer: 
    if message.partition in [0, 1, 2]:
        # do something with message.value
```

If you really want to read only from a subset of partitions, you can do something like:

```
consumer.assign([TopicPartition('foobar', 2)])
next_message = next(consumer)
```

would work for you. But I would suggest the first approach. Irrespective of the language of development you choose, all Kafka consumers must be implementing the above features.